# Windows Phone C# Long List Selector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add something from textblock but there's occurs a error that I can't handle with stackoverflow.

The code:

```
List<String> StringsList; 
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    StringsList.Add(textBox.Text.ToString());
    longListSelector.ItemsSource = StringsList; 
}
```

That should be simple code that add from the list some string to the Long List selector.  Could you please give me a tip or something? I was using the code from here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/LongListSelector-Demo-45364cc9#content

This is the error:

> $exception    {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object. at page3.Add_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick() at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.b__3()}    System.Exception
>   {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: Oh sorry, the error: +  $exception {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at page3.Add_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.<OnMouseLeftButtonUp>b__3()} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `List` use [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). Also make make sure its `Public`.

```
public ObservableCollection<String> StringsList { get; set; } 

    // Constructor 
    public MainPage() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 

        StringsList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "First Text Item", "Second Text Item", "Third Text Item" }; 

        DataContext = StringsList; 
    } 

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        StringsList.Add(textBox.Text); 
    }
```

> The ObservableCollection Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Please refer your attached sample carefully.